# Translating a label in a view

Tags: 7, views, i18n-l10n

I have a view in Drupal 7. I have too languages, english and finnish (the default language).
I want to translate the label (Puh) of a field in the view. When I search for the string with the translation interface it looks like in the picture.
[image]

The problem:
Puh (is a finnish translation) and seems to be in the wrong textbox.
There is no place to give the english translation.

Any hints?
Here are the Internationalization modules I have enabled:
Multilingual - Internationalization  Block languages (i18n_block)                          7.x-1.7
 Multilingual - Internationalization  Field translation (i18n_field)                        7.x-1.7
 Multilingual - Internationalization  Internationalization (i18n)                           7.x-1.7
 Multilingual - Internationalization  Menu translation (i18n_menu)                          7.x-1.7
 Multilingual - Internationalization  Multilingual content (i18n_node)                      7.x-1.7
 Multilingual - Internationalization  Multilingual select (i18n_select)                     7.x-1.7
 Multilingual - Internationalization  Path translation (i18n_path)                          7.x-1.7
 Multilingual - Internationalization  String translation (i18n_string)                      7.x-1.7
 Multilingual - Internationalization  Synchronize translations (i18n_sync)                  7.x-1.7
 Multilingual - Internationalization  Translation sets (i18n_translation)                   7.x-1.7
 Multilingual - Internationalization  Variable translation (i18n_variable)                  7.x-1.7